# why refreshing the loaded page in jquery resulting into loading page only

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have default.php and im loadiing another page letter.php into  of default.php

using the load method of jquery as follows

```
 $('div.banner a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).attr('href');
            $('.banner').load(page +'.php');
            return false;
        });
```

and its loading fine, but issue is when i press f5 after loading the page,
the default.php file is getting displayed with out the loaded content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       use the url hashing technique, as shown below

    $(document).ready(function(){   
    $(init);                          

    function init() {    
      ajax_page_handler();   
      page_load($(window.location).attr("hash"));             
    }

    function page_load($href)  
    {  
       if($href != undefined && $href.substring(0, 1) == '#')   
       {  
           $('.banner').load($href.substring(1));               
       }  
    }        
    function ajax_page_handler()
    {   
       $(window).bind('hashchange', function () 
       {                    
           $href = $(window.location).attr("hash");  
       page_load($href);        
         });   
    }   
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember what page should be loaded when de page refresh.

You can use cookies or any local storage.

Using a jquery cookie plugin:

```
$('div.banner a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).attr('href');
            $.cookie("pageToLoad",page);
            $('.banner').load(page +'.php');
            return false;
        });
```

When de page is refreshed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($.cookie("pageToLoad").length){
    $('.banner').load($.cookie("pageToLoad") +'.php');
}
```

});

Comment: Using cookies won't work if you send that link to someone wich hasn't got that cookie yet.

Answer (score 0):

That's because that is how AJAX works. It loads it for the page itself, but once you refresh it, every page you loaded using ajax is gone. I've written this simple function wich adds a hashtag to the URL. Then when you refresh the page with the hashtag, it starts the same AJAX event.

```
function loadfile(link, target){
    window.location.hash = '!'+ link;

    target.load(link);
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.hash != ''){
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        loadfile(hash.replace('#!', ''), $('.banner'));
    }

    $('div.banner a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        loadfile($(this).attr('href'), $('.banner'));
    });
});
```

```
<div class="banner">
    Dear potato,
    Blablabla. Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="letter.php">letter</a>.

    Love,
    Carrot.
</div>
```

Alternatively, instead of using hashtags you can also try using [history.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), but that's something new and not every user supports it yet.